# Odoo: on module install, how to load XML data before adding column in another table?

Tags: odoo

In an Odoo custom module, I extended `res_config_settings` to add a new setting `default_order_stage_id`, which is a required field that defaults to value from another model `OrderStage`in the same custom module, and `OrderStage` is preloaded with data (XML from the manifest file).

But the problem is that on install, I get the following error :

`Table 'res_config_settings': unable to set NOT NULL on column 'default_order_stage_id'`

So is there a way that on module install, to create and load the data to the `OrderStage` table, and **then** apply the new column to `res_config_settings` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround :

Setting the field `required=False`, I added `required="1"` on the field in the XML form view.

And then in the `post_init_hook`, searching for the unset setting, and setting it with the default I needed.